# Json array to url in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

My json array code ...

```
 private JSONArray getResults() {

    String myPath = "/data/data/com.example.sebastian.patientdetails/databases/" + "MyDBName.db";

    String myTable = "patients";


    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    String searchQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + myTable;
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(searchQuery, null);

    JSONArray resultSet = new JSONArray();

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
        JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();

        for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn; i++) {
            if (cursor.getColumnName(i) != null) {
                try {
                    if (cursor.getString(i) != null) {
                        Log.d("TAG_NAME", cursor.getString(i));
                        rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getString(i));
                    } else {
                        rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), "");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("TAG_NAME", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        resultSet.put(rowObject);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    Log.d("TAG_NAME", resultSet.toString());
    return resultSet;
}
```

How can i sent this json array to a url to connect with a web application? should i need to convert my json array.? Or how can i do it? How can i solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post entire JSON array(resultset) to PHP server using any Networking library. At PHP side, just decode that JSON array and save its value as per your need.
I give you some code in which i used Retrofit 2 library:

create Interface:

```
public interface YOURAPI{
 @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("add_to_db.php")
 Call<ResponseBody> insertSERVER(@Field("options") String jsonarray);
}
```

create another class APIClient:

```
private static final String BASE_URL ="http://yoururl.com/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient() {

    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

In main Activity:

```
YOURAPI itemAPI= Apiclient.getClient().create(YOURAPI.class);
                    Call<ResponseBody> servercall=itemAPI.insertSERVER(String.valueOf(resultset));
```

servercall.enqueue(new Constants.BackoffCallback(retryNum) {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                                BufferedReader reader;
                                String output = "";

```
                            try {
                                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.body().byteStream()));
                                output = reader.readLine();
                                Log.e("TAG",""+output);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailedAfterRetry(Throwable t) {
                        }
                    });
```